# Semi-supervised: Can I predict the label of purposely unlabelled observations?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, semi-supervised-learning

Let's say I have a data set with of length N. A small proportion N2 is labeled. Can I remove some labels and then 'reverse' this action with a trained neural network? I could then use the same process to fill the other (N - N2) rows with labels.

Comment: What is the purpose of your trained neural network? Is it to label the data like N2 is labelled? Or is it to provide new labels?

Comment: purpose is to label to have N labels.

Comment: N different labels? So each data point has a different label? Or do you mean each data point is labeled with a label already existing in N2?

Comment: not N labels, let's say 2 labels. N2 rows have 2 labels, the other N - N2 have no labels.

Comment: How is this different from supervised learning, trained on your labeled data, and used on your unlabeled data?